# Jquery UI drag drop not working with custom helper

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm building simple video editor timeline, I have created custom helper to create new div to place on timeline, but when I drop it changing back to original HTML.

not sure, how to achieve this, so, it correctly placed on the timeline

here preview https://fiddle.jshell.net/surjitsidhu/28cca2w5/1/show/

it can be edited here https://fiddle.jshell.net/surjitsidhu/28cca2w5/1

Comment: Did you try `ui.helper`, which would represent the custom helper?

Comment: yes, I got this solved, thanks